# Get element within function

Tags: javascript, function, element

I did:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
```

Now I want to do:

```
 element.myFunction();
```

but I have no idea how to get the element within the function. How do I do this?

```
function myFunction() {
// Get element here?
}
```

Comment: You need to use parameters.

Comment: Why do you want to "do" `element.myFunction()`?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Your question doesn't make much sense as it stands.

Comment: @Pointy I think it looks cleaner than myFunction(element), and I see it with other javascript functions.

Comment: @user2252246 the two constructions mean different things.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using the function to change the element, and passing it as an parameters doesn't make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom function to the prototype of `HTMLElement` objects like this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.customFunc = function(){
    // within this function, 'this' will refer 
    // to the element that it was called on
};
```

This means that any element will have access to the `customFunc` function as a method. For example:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.customFunc = function(){
    console.log(this.id);
};

// now assuming your HTML contains #myElement and #anotherElem:
document.getElementById('myElement').customFunc(); // displays 'myElement'
document.getElementById('anotherElem').customFunc(); // displays 'anotherElem'
```

Obviously, be careful with the naming of the function, as you probably don't want to overwrite any pre-existing methods or properties.

Comment: Thanks! I used this solution. I only created my own function called 'Element' instead of using HTMLElement. This way I don't have to be careful and I have full control. (Used a little bit of MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript )

Answer (score 0):

In javascript since you are declaring

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
```

You already have the element in the global scope, so you can simply call it inside your function

```
function myFunction() {
  // Do something with your element
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're instead declaring your element inside another function or if you want to use the same function for different elements, you must use a parameter. This is the call:

```
myFunction(element)
```

And this is the function

```
function myFunction(element) {
  // Do something with your element
}
```

Comment: The idea of the function is that I can use the same code again for different elements. Using it as a parameter doesn't make it clear that I edit/change the element.

Comment: Yes, please see the edit to my reply. You can use your element if you pass it as an argument of the function itself

Comment: I did that, but it feels like it doesn't make it clear that I edit/change the element. It looks like bad/unclear code. While element.myFunction() clearly shows what i'm doing. I searched a little more, and I found that I need to add a method, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain your your function with the element, then you need to extend the prototype of the `HTMLElement`, or `Node`, objects:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.myFunction = function (parameters) {
    var elementToActOn = this;
    elementToActOn.style.color = 'green';
    return this; // for further chaining
}
```

Or:

```
Node.prototype.myFunction = function (parameters) {
    var elementToActOn = this;
    elementToActOn.style.color = 'green';
    return this; // for further chaining
}
```

With this approach `this`, inside the `myFunction()` method, will refer to the element selected by:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').myFunction();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aLdKD/), using the `HTMLElement` prototype.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aLdKD/1/), using the `Node` prototype.

Similarly, if all you want to do is pass the element-node to the function without 'explicitly' passing it as an argument:

```
function myFunction () {
    this.style.color = 'red';
}

document.getElementById('elementID').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aLdKD/2).

If you'd prefer to act on multiple elements, selected by `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` (among others), then you'd need, instead, to extend the `NodeList` prototype, for example:

```
NodeList.prototype.myFunction = function (parameters) {
    var elements = this;
    [].forEach.call(elements, function(a){
        a.style.color = 'green';
    });
    return this; // for chaining
}

/* calling the function, with a simple demonstration of why you might want to
   chain, by returning 'this': */
var len = document.getElementsByClassName('elementClass').myFunction().length;
console.log(len);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aLdKD/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want

```
    <input type = "button" value = "Next" id = "btnNext" />

    <script>
    HTMLElement.prototype.myFunction = function()
    {
        alert(this.id);
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById("btnNext");
    elem.myFunction();

    </script>
```

Comment: That was what I wanted! I changed it a little bit (see answer above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
```

It looks like you want to have a function using the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(this); // logs `this` (which will be `element`)
}
```

And rather than setting a property so you could `element.myFunction();`, I'd suggest using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), i.e.

```
myFunction.call(element); // element gets logged
```

Answer (score -1):

rather u should try this , i will give an example for a div with onclick

```
<script>

function myfunc(){
getElementById('sample').whatever function u want
}
</script>
```

And in the body u can use -

```
<body>
<div id="sample" onclick="myfunc()">The function will happen onclicking the div</div>
</body>
```